# Circular dependancy in typescript error in Record type and not in an object type

Tags: typescript

What is the differences between the 2 types that one type throws a TS error and the second type doesn't?

```
type ScopeItem =
    | string
    | {
            all: string;
            team: string;
      };

type ScopesTree = Record<string, ScopeItem | Record<string, ScopesTree>>; // error: Type alias 'ScopesTree' circular references itself
type ScopesTree2 = Record<string, ScopeItem | { [key: string]: ScopesTree2 }>; // no error
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like TS can construct a type out of `ScopesTree2` but not `ScopesTree`, which also shows up as `any`. It's essentially the same type though, so there might be a problem with the `Record` type here.

Comment: TypeScript hasn't yet "computed" what `Record<string, ScopeTree>` resolves to, so when it sees `ScopeTree` again, it freaks out because it contains the same expression. The index signature works, because TypeScript has already "computed" the type. It's `{ [key: string]: ScopeTrees2 }`. If you have written some of your own programming languages, this might make more sense to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164) of Typescript and you need to ignore this as of now.

Please use: `type ScopesTree2 = Record<string, ScopeItem | { [key: string]: ScopesTree2 }>; // no error` in your code instead of Record.

There is a brief discussion on this and an [open issue.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41164)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any difference between the two, it's just that your IDE is showing one error at a time. If you comment the type ScopesTree then it will show the error on the other type

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).